# Exporting from ssrs 2008 report to multiple column in csv

Tags: reporting-services

I have ssrs report. When I export that report to csv , and when I open that csv file in ms-excel, some data is coming in column A and some data is coming in column B .Can you help me in getting whole data to column A only ? In report, DataElementOutput property of each textbox is also set to 'Auto'.

Answer (score 0):

Without more to go on it seems you have two columns and they are displayed as such.  If you just want a single column consider doing an expression like this in SSRS:(click the cell and choose 'Expression' in 2008 and higher)

```
=Fields!(FieldName).Value & " " & Fields!(FieldName2).Value
```

This would put two fields in one column but seperate them with a (space).